# Adding headers to a table I have scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I have been following an online tutorial but rather than using the tutorial data which comes with headers I want to use the following code:

The problem I have is that my table has no headers so it is using the first row as the header. How can I set defined headers of "Ride" and "Queue Time"?

Thanks

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd

url='http://www.ridetimes.co.uk/'

page = requests.get(url)

doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)

tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

r_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

col=[]
i=0
#For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    print '%d:"%s"'%(i,name)
    col.append((name,[]))
    print(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(col,columns=["Ride","Queue Time"])
               Ride Queue Time
0  Spinball Whizzer         []
1            0 mins         []
```

If I am correct then this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to get the table, then just assign the column names:

```
import pandas as pd

url='http://www.ridetimes.co.uk/'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

df.columns = ['Ride', 'Queue Time']
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
               Ride             Queue Time
0  Spinball Whizzer                 0 mins
1           Nemesis                 5 mins
2          Oblivion                 5 mins
3        Wicker Man                 5 mins
4        The Smiler                10 mins
5              Rita                20 mins
6          TH13TEEN                25 mins
7         Galactica  Currently Unavailable
8        Enterprise  Currently Unavailable
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the same source the page does to update values which returns json. You add a random number to the url to prevent cached results being served. This does all group types not just `thrill`.

```
import requests
import random 
import pandas as pd

i = random.randint(1,1000000000000000000)
r = requests.get('http://ridetimes.co.uk/queue-times-new.php?r=' + str(i)).json() #to prevent cached results being served
df = pd.DataFrame([(item['ride'], item['time']) for item in r], columns = ['Ride', ' Queue Time'])
print(df)
```

If you want only `thrill` group then amend to this line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(item['ride'], item['time']) for item in r if item['group'] == 'Thrill'], columns = ['Ride', ' Queue Time'])
```